# How to load layer pre-unselected?

Tags: qgis

I want to load multiple raster data files into a QGIS project. In total the are about 2,5 GB in size. Is there a way to pre-unselect the layer prior to the loading process to not crash the whole system?

Comment: Load them one by one. Or load them in a turned off group .

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck the render checkbox below the map window, then add them, uncheck all the rasters:

[image]